# PowerShell Как узнать когда был запущен процесс «explorer». Какой это день недели?

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

PowerShell Как узнать когда был запущен процесс «explorer». Какой это день недели?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить время последнего запуска процесса explorer:

```
(Get-Process -Name explorer).StartTime
```

Получить день недели когда он был запущен

```
(Get-Process -Name explorer).StartTime.DayOfWeek
```